# German citizen, US LLC, living in Germany: Can I use an VWP?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, business-travel

So:

- I am a German citizen with no US visa status
- I am one of two members of an US LLC (the other member is US citizen)
- I am getting paid in the form of member distributions in USD

My questions are:

1. Can I legally enter the US for 90 days through the Visa-Waiver Program for business purposes while continuously being paid? (My activities would be limited to consulting with the other member and signing contracts.)
2. If not, could I do *1.* if payments stopped while I am in the US?
3. Could I enter for touristic purposes for 90 days while continuously being paid if I suspend all my business activities?

Comment: Are you being paid your "member distributions" because you are doing work for the LLC, or just because you own the LLC?

Comment: I do participate in meetings and negotiate contracts occasionally. Is that considered work? @DJClayworth

Comment: Is doing that the reason you are paid? Would you still be paid if other people did those things for you?

Comment: @DJClayworth Technically yes, I would still be paid if these tasks would be delegated to another person. The actual, legal reason for payments is the LLCs operating agreement and not my 'work'.